# R plotting proportions problem - ggplot making plot that looks like a table

Tags: r, ggplot2, binomial-cdf

I am trying to make a plot of proportions of a binomial distribution (yes/no) depending on one ordinal and one continuous variable. Somehow when including the continuous one as color of the dots the appearance of the plot radically changes. Can someone help me with how to include the third variable without having the plot turn into below table-looking result?

Code as follows:

```
#making table with proportions of people who switch (1),
## after arsenic level and education.

educ_switch <- prop.table(table(welldata$educ[welldata$switch==1],
                                welldata$arsenic[welldata$switch==1],  
                                welldata$switch[welldata$switch==1]))
educ_switch <- as_data_frame(educ_switch, make.names=TRUE)

#remove observations where the proportion is 0

educ_switch1 <- educ_switch[which (educ_switch$proportion>0),]
p <- ggplot(educ_switch1, aes(x = educ, y=proportion))
```

If I do `p + geom_point()`

I get the following picture:

[image: ggplot with overlapping points]

But when I try to distinguish the third variable by coloring it with `p + geom_point(aes(colour = arsenic))`

I get this weird looking thing instead:

[image: ggplot, only legend visible]

Comment: Take a look at what you see when you plot with `ggplot(educ_switch1, aes(x = educ, y=proportion)) + geom_point(aes(colour = arsenic), show.legend = F)`. That's just the legend

Comment: it looks like `arsenic` got turned into a factor. Can you check your workflow for reading it in and see if you can get that to *not* happen, or is necessary convert back to numeric with `as.numeric(as.character(arsenic))` ?

Comment: Thank you both for your help! Converted arsenic with `as.numeric` and it solved the problem! And as Dij said, it was just the legend showing on the pic I posted, so removing that enabled me to see the plot properly (though the factor issue still needed to be solved for the plot to make sense).